# Validating Checkboxes with Coldfusion

Tags: html, validation, checkbox, coldfusion

I have checkboxes on a webpage that need to be validated using coldfusion, how might I validate at least one checkbox for each group needs to be answered?

```
<div name="multanswerheader" id="multanswerheader" style="width:100%;">
            <div name="multanswerques" id="multanswerques">
                <label class="multanswerques">Ques 1:</label>
                <label class="multanswerques">Ques 2:</label>
                <label class="multanswerques">Ques 3:</label>
                <label class="multanswerques">Ques 4:</label>
                <label class="multanswerques">Ques 5:</label>
            </div>
            <div name="multanswera" id="multanswera">
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio1" value="1" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio1,"1") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>A</input></div>
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio2" value="1" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio2,"1") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>A</input></div>
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio3" value="1" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio3,"1") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>A</input></div>
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio4" value="1" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio4,"1") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>A</input></div>
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio5" value="1" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio5,"1") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>A</input></div>
            </div>
            <div name="multanswerb" id="multanswerb">
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio1" value="2" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio1,"2") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>B</input></div>
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio2" value="2" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio2,"2") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>B</input></div>
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio3" value="2" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio3,"2") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>B</input></div>
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio4" value="2" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio4,"2") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>B</input></div>
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio5" value="2" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio5,"2") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>B</input></div>
            </div>
            <div name="multanswerc" id="multanswerc">
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio1" value="3" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio1,"3") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>C</input></div>
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio2" value="3" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio2,"3") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>C</input></div>
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio3" value="3" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio3,"3") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>C</input></div>
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio4" value="3" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio4,"3") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>C</input></div>
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio5" value="3" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio5,"3") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>C</input></div>
            </div>
            <div name="multanswerd" id="multanswerd">
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio1" value="4" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio1,"4") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>D</input></div>
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio2" value="4" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio2,"4") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>D</input></div>
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio3" value="4" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio3,"4") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>D</input></div>
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio4" value="4" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio4,"4") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>D</input></div>
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio5" value="4" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio5,"4") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>D</input></div>
            </div>
            <div name="multanswere" id="multanswere">
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio1" value="5" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio1,"5") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>E</input></div>
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio2" value="5" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio2,"5") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>E</input></div>
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio3" value="5" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio3,"5") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>E</input></div>
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio4" value="5" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio4,"5") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>E</input></div>
                <div class="multanswerques"><input type="checkbox" name="multradio5" value="5" <cfif ListFind(form.multradio5,"5") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>>E</input></div>
            </div>                
        </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example from a form I've done.

```
<cfif isDefined("form.submit")>
    <cfif form.checkbox1a EQ "" >
        <p class="text-error">Please check at least one answer below</p>
    </cfif>
</cfif>

<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
    <legend>*Pick some chips</legend>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1a" id="checkbox1a" value="a" <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox1a,"a") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
    <label for="checkbox1a">Cheetos</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1a" id="checkbox2a" value="b" <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox1a,"b") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
    <label for="checkbox2a">Doritos</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1a" id="checkbox3a" value="c" <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox1a,"c") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
    <label for="checkbox3a">Fritos</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1a" id="checkbox4a" value="d" <cfif ListFind(form.checkbox1a,"d") GT 0>checked="checked"</cfif>/>
    <label for="checkbox4a">Sun Chips</label>
</fieldset>
```

You must make sure your checkboxes have the same names, but different values. Then just make a check to see if that name has a value or not. I did mine before the checkboxes because I wanted the error message to appear above the boxes, but since the CF is only triggered on the form submit, it will execute second.

Comment: You do realize that if form.checkbox1a is not submitted in the form this code will error right?  Unchecked checkboxes are not submitted and not part of the form scope.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you mean... The form I have these in works as I would like it to.

Comment: @Zorpix - That is because you are declaring a default for `form.checkbox1a` elsewhere in your code. So it is always defined. Remove the default (and the extra `ListFind` code) and the above will error if none of the boxes are checked.

Answer (score 1):

You should be doing this in the client not in ColdFusion. Unchecked checkboxes are not submitted to the server.  You would have to test for the fact they are not part of the form scope on the server.